# Definition versus initialization of a variable

Tags: c

I believe i am right, but just making sure
`int c;` declares `c`,
`c = 5;` initializes `c` to be equal to `5`,
and 
`int c = 5;` both declares and initializes `c`.
Am I correct on all of these? And initialization is just the first value the variable is set to correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int c;
```

declares and defines `c`.

```
c = 5;
```

is not an *initializer*, but it *assigns* the value `5` to `c`, which has the same effect.

An initializer is a syntactic construct, part of a declaration. An assignment is a different syntactic construct that does more or less the same thing.

This:

```
int c = 5;
```

declares and initializes `c`; the `5` is the initializer.

This:

```
int c;
c = 5;
```

has the same effect, but there is no initializer.

(You can informally say that assigning a value to a variable "initializes" it, but it does so without using an initializer.)

One case where the distinction is important:

```
const int c = 5;
```

This initializes `c` to `5`. You can't do the same thing with an assignment because you can't assign to a `const` (read-only) object.

Answer (score 2):

Initialization is the setting of the initial value of a variable, so you are correct.

This is the first line off the Wikipedia article on initialization:

> In computer programming, initialization is the assignment of an initial value for a data object or variable.

Answer (score 1):

All your statements are correct, but you are missing one definition, the difference between definition and declaration.

`int c;` both declares **and** defines `c`, but does not initialize it.

`extern int c;` will declare it but not define it. (It does not allocate storage.)

Comment: It is slightly more subtle than that: `int c;` is a *tentative definition*. This is why `int c; int c = 5;` is accepted. `int c=5; int c=2;` is rejected for the obvious reasons, and so is `int c=5; int c=5;`, since it attempts to define `c` twice.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, If you can find the standard reference, I'll modify it and reference the standard. I can't find it currently.

Comment: We must be inside a function, otherwise `int c; c = 5;` would have been an error; so it would not be a tentative definition.

Comment: Since there is ambiguity here, I'll let my answer stand as is, with the comments adding clarification. If one of you feels very strongly about this, please feel free to edit.